# iAd rotates to landscape mode on iPad - iOS 9

Tags: ios, iad, landscape, portrait

I have a portrait mode only app and opening or clicking on iAd bannerviews opens correctly on iPhone, but on iPad the iAd rotates to landscape mode, which messes up my views when exiting the iAd.

So far, I have made sure the app is forced to open in portrait mode only both with code, .plist, target and tried with following code, but no matter what I do, when I click iAd banner on iPad, it rotates to landscape mode. Hope someone can shed some light on this.

```
    bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    navControl.view.addSubview(bannerView)
```

Added to both the navcontroller and all following viewcontrollers:

```
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Update: I found that the iAd view rotation only happens on older iPad devices (Retina and 2). iPad Air and Pro open up the iAd without rotating the view. I still not sure what setting I can set to ensure iAd does not rotate the view to landscape.

Comment: By the way, Apple said: "[The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a)"